# Why are individual measurements often normally distributed?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, normal-distribution

So, I believe I at least mostly understand the intuition behind the derivation of the Central Limit Theorem, which essentially pivots on the idea that the sum of independent variables, taken from the same PDF, will itself be normally distributed. There are a few derivations that I understand (involving convolution and Fourier transforms etc). However, my question is why are certain individual measurements that are NOT in any way summed and averaged (as per in the definition of CLT)- the height of individuals within a population say, *also* distributed by the Gaussian?

I saw on a previous thread re a similar topic someone mention that in this case, the individual measurement taken, of height say, is *itself* inherently made up of other variables (environment, genetic etc) and therefore these do provide the same “summed up” approximation. My problem with this, which might be inherent misunderstanding, is that all of the subtle contributing independent variables that sum to this final value are presumably not produced from the same pdfs? which is a fundamental aspect of the CLT derivation.

I hope this makes sense... I’m absolutely intrigued to know the answer or anyone’s thoughts.

Comment: Cross Validated's @whuber makes a nice comment:

"Your argument begins to suggest--quite plausibly, in my view--that there may be a psychological answer to the question, such as groupthink: when everybody in your field sees normal distributions, who are you to say otherwise? This would go especially for fields of inquiry where statistical procedures are viewed as pedestrian tools, necessary perhaps to sanctify a paper for publication, but otherwise of little inherent value or interest."

Comment: There are also "central limit theorems" that do not require the individual random variables to be identically distributed.  For example, you might look at [Lindeberg's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition).